# JavaScript: curious to know if "if statements can substitute .include method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a .filter() method and a given solution has a .include() method in it. I was trying to solve the problem using an inner loop, next I switched to .filter and attempted using an if statement in the inner function.

Below is a code sample:

```
let arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let arrayTwo = [2,4,6,8,10,'water'];

const filterComparism=(arr1,arr2)=>{
  let newArray=[];
/**return arr1.filter(item=>arr2.includes(item)); this line of Code would solve the issue. is there an alternative step to solve below?
*/
for(let i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j< arr2.length; j++){


    
        newArray.push(arr1===arr2? return true);
  
        }
    }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(filterComparism(arrayOne,arrayTwo));




const filterComparism=(arr1,arr2)=>{

    /**return arr1.filter(item=>arr2.includes(item)); this line of Code would solve the issue. is there an alternative step to solve below?
    */


    return arr1.filter(item=>{
      if(item===arr2){
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    }
```

is there an alternative method to achieve this using an if statement in the inner function or using inner loops to compare values.

Comment: `item===arr2` and `arr2.includes(item)` do two very different things.  It's not clear to me what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Comparing each item of the first array to the entire 2nd array will obviously not work; you indeed need an inner loop. Your question text it pretty confusing, please clarify *exactly* which alternate solution you're looking for (and why, given that you have working code). Since your 2nd attempt also uses .filter(), it sounds like you're asking for a way to do .includes() manually using if, which is absolutely possible but requires iterating over the 2nd array.

Comment: @ChrisG The last part of your response simplifiers what I was asking. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @David I understand they are 2 different things but I was thinking having the value in the if statement would return true and that is what will be used in the filter. I cleaned the code multiple times and think I uploaded an incomplete code. If I had the if statement in an inner loop that iterates through the second array, would it work?

Comment: <pre><code>
let arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let arrayTwo = [2,4,6,8,10,'water'];

const filterComparism=(arr1,arr2)=>{
  let newArray=[];
/**return arr1.filter(item=>arr2.includes(item)); this line of Code would solve the issue. is there an alternative step to solve below?
*/
for(let i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j< arr2.length; j++){


    
        newArray.push(arr1===arr2? return true);
  
        }
    }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(filterComparism(arrayOne,arrayTwo));

</pre></code>

Comment: 1. Please clean up your code 2. please don't post new code as comment 3. what's up with that .push() code...? 4. you're looking for this: https://jsfiddle.net/xowtj965/

Comment: @JosephMusa to be clear, it isn't a good idea to respond to comments with a comment. Just [edit] this question and make changes to address requests for clarification.